# PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API libCurl gives 411 error with NTLM auth

Tags: php, sharepoint, curl, libcurl

I'm using the Git [PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API) library with NTLM auth. It sends a POST request via lib cURL (I'm running Windows PHP 5.5.11 with lib cURL 7.35.0).

Problem is that the NTLM auth response generated by cURL doesn't include a `Content-Length` header and SharePoint 2013 doesn't seem to like that. It returns an HTTP 411 error, content length missing

I've found discussions of this issue in [multiple](http://osdir.com/ml/web.curl.library/2003-12/msg00243.html) places but no actual solutions. Thanks for any ideas.

**Calling via cURL** from [SoapClientAuth.php](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API/blob/master/src/Thybag/Auth/SoapClientAuth.php)

```
$ch = curl_init($location);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->Username . ':' . $this->Password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, TRUE);
if ($DEBUGGING) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

**First Request**

```
POST http://sp2013server.com/marketing/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: sp2013server.arx.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection"
Content-Length: 251
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas... blah
```

**First Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1255
SPRequestGuid: 5b93869c-5b72-8091-555a-8d0d25f77b1e
request-id: 5b93869c-5b72-8091-555a-8d0d25f77b1e
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 8
SPIisLatency: 6
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420
Date: Sat, 12 Apr 2014 17:42:49 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

**Second Request (generated by CURL, not by a client call)**

```
POST http://sp2013server.arx.com/marketing/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
Authorization: NTLM TlRMxxxxxxxxxxx==
Host: sp2013server.arx.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection"
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Second Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Sat, 12 Apr 2014 17:42:50 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 344

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Re: the discussion over on the github https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API/issues/58

I've added a suggested potential fix for this issue to the develop branch of the library (https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API/tree/develop). Would you be able to let me know if this resolves the problem?

Comment: Hi Carl, thank you for your time on this. Unfortunately, I'm on to new projects so won't be able to work on this for awhile. I was able to get it to work by resending the login (I think). The extra traffic is a waste but it then worked.